# BitLocker Use and Linux

Tags: usb-drive, disk-encryption

Is it possible to have BitLocker enabled on a USB device and still be able to access files from the device within Linux?  I have a drive I need to keep encrypted but need to access on both Linux and Windows boxes.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/376533/how-to-access-a-bitlocker-encrypted-drive-in-linux

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/376533/how-to-access-a-bitlocker-encrypted-drive-in-linux

Comment: The usual solution for cross-OS disk encryption is Truecrypt/Veracrypt.

Comment: While I know other solutions exist, I'm truly interested in whether it is possible to implement with BitLocker.

Comment: Dislocker can be used to access files on a Bitlocker encrypted drive, but not easily modify them. A downside is you'll need plenty of disk space as you need to make a copy of that volume with dd.